# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable (exoPlayer) flutter

Tags: flutter, exoplayer

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DownloadNotificationHelper found in modules jetified-exoplayer-core-2.18.0-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.18.0) and jetified-exoplayer-ui-2.14.1-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.14.1)

[image]

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: No, I haven't found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem:

- Try to delete the `.gradle` folder -> path: `android/.gradle` folder.
- then `flutter clean` `flutter pub get`